# NSRangeException when searching for bytes near end of NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsrange

I want to check the last 2 bytes of files in my app to make sure they are not corrupt .jpg's

`rangeOfData:options:range:` looks like a good option, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get a proper `NSRange`.  The range I am looking for is starting near the end of the `NSData`, up to the end.

Here is what I have so far:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSRange range = {([imageData length]-8),[imageData length]};
NSString *str = @"FFD9";
NSData *jpgTest = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange found = [imageData rangeOfData:jpgTest options:NSDataSearchBackwards range:range];
```

Here is the error I get:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData rangeOfData:options:range:]: range {14954, 14962} enxceeds data length 14962'

How do I properly get the range to search the last few bytes of my `NSData`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second member of `NSRange` is not the end point of the range but its length. So in your case it should be:

```
NSRange range = {([imageData length]-8), 8};
```

Comment: I guess I could have just looked at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html  - thanks!

Comment: Indeed. I find that the documentation answers almost all questions I have.